# Spring boot and logging location

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot 1.3.7.

In my application.properties I have

```
logging.file=syste.log
logging.path=/home/apps/log
```

My jar file is located in /home/apps

At runtime, logging file is located where apps is running (/home/apps).

Why the value in logging.path is not used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging-file-output) specifying **both** `logging.file` and `logging.path` is not supported (or handled), you should specify the full path in the `logging.file` setting:

```
logging.file=/home/apps/log/syste.log
```